# How to load different viewcontrollers depening on previous highscore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Im making a game and right now i have 9 levels. To level up you have to score 10 points. That will save on a label.

So when the viewwillappear loads, and the label has the score of 10, they go to the next viewcontroller.

But, the problem is that when you load the app again, it doesnt look like i want it to. Because the previous view loads first, and then it recognizes that you have the score (10) on the label and then after a few seconds switches back to the  next level.

Is there any ways i can make it just make it quickly load the level they are supposed to be on? (just like a quiz) When they load the app they go straight to the level they was on while quitting the app, instad of waiting for the view to load and wait a millisecond to switch to the view they are supposed to be on.

Answer (score 1):

When it is in background and user came back if you want to do something you can set desired view controller as root view controller of your navigation controller or you can add it to the window as per your requirements or based on your logic in this method.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

     NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"aKey"];

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        ViewController1 *viewController1 = (ViewController1 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1Identifier"];
        ViewController2 *viewController2 = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2Identifier"];

     if(score > 10){
          if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]]) {
             //but you want to present here secondViewController you can do this 
             [self.window setRootViewController:viewController2];
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter please suggest the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Do you have any example? Like if the highscorelabel == 10 they get teleported to viewcontroller 2 before viewcontroller 1 loads?:)

Comment: yeah sure. How are you managing score? How are you saving them?

Comment: Im at school right now so i havent tried it out but i will :) Thanks :)!

Comment: I save them with NSUserdefaults. The game mode is hitting a image with another image. when they hit the correct image the scorelabel changes to 10 and saves with  NSUserdefaults. Right after scoring they go to level 2. And when they go out of the application and go back in, they will automaticly go to level 2. Can you show me how you would do this? (I can show some code when i come home in 5 hours

Answer (score -1):

If I understand right your needs you can use a different approach: store the value in the NSUserDefault (so it's persistent and you can retrive it from any point of your application) then in the UIAppDelegate (that's loaded before any view controller) check for it and load the right one.
Hope this helps

Comment: as always dumb downvoter express their hate for everything is not "pure blood" software q&a... moron....